# Network driver issue on 5.4 kernel for I219 8086:15fa

Tags: drivers, network-interface, hardware, ethernet, intel

had today missing network driver on a *Linux Mint 20 (5.4.0-73-generic)* with embedded mobo network card

> Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (14) I219-V [8086:15fa] (rev 11)

Didn't think that this was possible with a descent new kernel. (5.4)

Motherboard (MoBo) btw is *ASRock model: B560M-ITX/ac*

would like to share a few command which helped me to

- identify that it was a missing driver,
- how to install the driver.
- how to know which kernel will include it.

Answer (score 1):

similar for me. I Installed the Ubuntu 18.04.6 server image and had the Intel i219-LM on my Lenovo P350 as unclaimed.

make and gcc was missing in this install also but still the driver installation failed.

sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-18.04

did the job. After this the driver installation worked for me.

thanks to: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1208978/intel-corporation-device-80860d4f-is-not-supported-on-ubuntu-18-04-3

Many thanks - Mark

Answer (score 0):

CMD which help to narrow it down to missing driver

```bsh
    sudo lshw -class network
```

Which had:

***-network UNCLAIMED**

I compared my HW ID **8086:15fa** here and according to this https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/E1000E.html included in Kernel 5.5–5.11, 5.12-rc+HEAD (so my 5.4 is just one version to old)

here few cmd to check

```bsh
lspci -knn
sudo lshw -class network
sudo lspci -v
dmesg | grep "00:1f.6"  #based on previous output
dmesg | grep "8086:15fa"  #based on previous output
```

example output

```bsh
tilo@trex-lx:~$ sudo lspci -v
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (14) I219-V (rev 11)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Ethernet Connection (14) I219-V
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255
    Memory at a3400000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+

tilo@trex-lx:~$ dmesg | grep "00:1f.6"
[    0.350866] pci 0000:00:1f.6: [8086:15fa] type 00 class 0x020000
[    0.350928] pci 0000:00:1f.6: reg 0x10: [mem 0xa3400000-0xa341ffff]
[    0.351165] pci 0000:00:1f.6: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold

tilo@trex-lx:~$ lspci -knn
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (14) I219-V [8086:15fa] (rev 11)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Ethernet Connection (14) I219-V [1849:15fa]


tilo@trex-lx:~$ sudo lshw -class network -short
H/W path           Device          Class          Description
=============================================================
/0/100/1d/0        wlp3s0          network        Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak]
/0/100/1f.6                        network        Ethernet Connection (14) I219-V


tilo@trex-lx:~$ sudo lshw -class network 
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
---removed---
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: Ethernet Connection (14) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       version: 11
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:a3400000-a341ffff

tilo@trex-lx:~/Downloads/Preboot_26.1/APPS/BootUtil/Linux_x64$ sudo ./bootutil64e
Connection to QV driver failed - please reinstall it!

Intel(R) Ethernet Flash Firmware Utility
BootUtil version 1.7.27.1
Copyright (C) 2003-2020 Intel Corporation

Type BootUtil -? for help

Port Network Address Location Series  WOL Flash Firmware                Version
==== =============== ======== ======= === ============================= =======
  1   A--removed-D     0:31.6 Gigabit N/A FLASH Not Present
```

Intel driver download:
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005480/ethernet-products.html
https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/15817

Install see here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1094806/37213

```bsh
## unpack
tar xfv e1000e-3.8.4.tar.gz
##change dir
cd e1000e-3.8.4/src/
## install
sudo make install
## reboot
```

**Note**: needs to be repeated after kernel update.

Also Ubuntu LTS and Linux mint support to use newer kernel (via HWE stack) to avoid the manual install of the driver.